# RDD with no Partioner & Partition size

Tags: apache-spark

I am curios to know the relation b/w an RDD with no Partioner & its partition size. Say take the example of `map()` transformation. It returns an RDD which has no Partitioner(as expected).

```
scala> val input = sc.parallelize(List(1, 2, 2, 3))
input: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[Int] = ParallelCollectionRDD[0] at parallelize at <console>:21

scala>  val sum = input.map(x => x + 1)
sum: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[Int] = MapPartitionsRDD[1] at map at <console>:23

scala> sum.partitioner;
res0: Option[org.apache.spark.Partitioner] = None
```

When I try to find the Partition size, I see the Partition size is `8`

```
scala> sum.partitions.size
res1: Int = 8
```

Considering there is no Partitioner for the RDD `sum`, I was expecting the partition size to be `1`(ie No Partition). How do we have a partition size of `> 1` without a Partioner for the RDD(`sum`)?

Answer (score 1):

If patitioner is None, then it means partitioning is not based upon characteristic of data but distribution is random and guaranteed to be uniform across nodes. so the patitions.size is >1

reference: https://techmagie.wordpress.com/2015/12/19/understanding-spark-partitioning/